# Ant <copy todir> zipfileset with prefix

Tags: ant

Let's say that `C:/dir2/` has one file called `file2.txt`
And that `C:/dir3/`has one file called `file3.txt`

This ant script:

```
<copy todir="C:/dir1">
    <zipfileset dir="C:/dir2" prefix="dirprefix2"/>
    <zipfileset dir="C:/dir3" prefix="dirprefix3"/>
</copy>
```

copies the files to:

```
C:/dir1/file2.txt
C:/dir1/file3.txt
```

But I wanted it to copy to:

```
C:/dir1/dirprefix2/file2.txt
C:/dir1/dirprefix3/file3.txt
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `prefix` is used only when *creating* archives.

The following should work fine:

```
<copy todir="C:/dir1/dirprefix">
    <zipfileset dir="C:/dir2"/>
</copy>
```

Alternatively, you can use macros:

```
<macrodef name="mycp">
  <attribute name="dir"/>
  <attribute name="todir" default="C:/dir1"/>
  <attribute name="prefix"/>
  <sequential>
    <copy todir="@{todir}/@{prefix}">
        <fileset dir="@{dir}/"/>
    </copy>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

then you will have one line per directory, like this:

```
<mycp dir="C:/dir2" prefix="dirprefix2"/>
<mycp dir="C:/dir3" prefix="dirprefix3"/>
...
```

Comment: Well while this does work, it would increase my script considerably since I wanted to do this to several zipfileset, each with a different prefix. I should had mentioned that on my question. I will edit it.

Comment: so you really need one line per one directory ... I am afraid that won't be possible.
If two lines per dir were acceptable, then perhaps `mapper` especially `globmapper` could help... otherwise I can only imagine sort of data-driven approach.

Comment: I just added the macro-based alternative, that makes it single line per directory :)

Comment: Is there any way to pass one or more filesets instead of passing a string to the macro? For example: <mycp prefix="dirprefix"><fileset ...> </mycp>?

Comment: yes, you can use the "element" subelement instead of attribute - look here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html